анимация с обьектом



body {
    background-color: #040206;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header-inner {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1200px;
    display: flex;
   align-items: center;

   justify-content: space-around;
}

.header {
    background-color: #020103;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    max-height: 100px;
    display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-around;
   position: relative;
}

.border {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px #282729 solid;
}

.container-1 {

    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 40%;

}

.container-1 img {
    width: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-link {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.6;

    margin-left: 30px;
}


.container-2 {
    border: 2px #282729 solid;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 506px;
    padding: 15px;
    max-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}

.nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
   text-align: center;
height: 100%;
padding-left: 5px;
}

.container-3 {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 120px;
    max-height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

.button {
    background-color: #391c67;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.text-button {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.text-button:hover {
    color: black;
    width: 120310px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Change Image</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

    <header class="header">
        <div class="border"></div>
        <div class="header-inner">
        <div class="container-1">
            <img src="photo/header.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="container-2">
            <nav class="nav">
                <a href="" class="nav-link">Features</a>
                <a href="" class="nav-link">Developers</a>
                <a href="" class="nav-link">Company</a>
                <a href="" class="nav-link">Blog</a>
                <a href="" class="nav-link">Changelog</a>

            </nav>
    </div>
        <div class="container-3">
            <div class="button">
                <h1 class="text-button" >Join waitilist</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </header>


<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



вопрос странный но почему я не могу нормально стилизовать container-3 если я пишу в него hover и cursor pointer он просто не добавляется, даже как текст на странице копировать не получается, навестись на него и ожидать какой то анимации когда я добавлял active , hover не получается, что не так?

просто у вас <div class="border"></div> его перекрывает

я убрал полностью border да, container-1 стал работать который я не упоминал но container-3 так и остался не исправим

у вас внутри .container-3 еще один div с классом .button, который имеет 100% ширины и высоты, следовательно, наводя курсор на .container-3 вы наводитесь на .button, попробуйте задать :hover для .button и убедитесь в этом
